# Stop collect and r/collect cookies from being sent to client

Tags: php, apache, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

We are trying to stop the delivery of some marketing cookies to our users. namely the google collect and r/collect cookies. but we have no idea how they are appearing to being with.

We are only implementing google analytics on google tag manager with no display network or cross device or browser checking.

is there a way via php our at server level on apache to stop these cookies from going out?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by "google collect cookie", but integration with GDN is enabled when you enable demographic reports in GA (this causes the GA request to be redirected via the doubleclick domain), so that might be part of your problem. Cookies are set by the client, so you cannot suppress Javascript cookies with serverside settings.

Comment: There is a cookie from google called collec & r/collect these are marketing cookies with personal information. I need to stop them. It will be the demographics thanks for pointing me there